# Fallback Eureka Server Configuration for Discovery Clients?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

Most of the Eureka client configurations I have seen look like this:

```
eureka:  
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Is it possible to configure alternate zones, such that if the default fails the client switches over to the alternate?  Also is it possible to use hystrix as a circuit breaker to switch over to an alternate Eureka instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceUrl is a map. Each entry is for a different zone (defaultZone is the default zone).

```
eureka:  
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
      zoneA: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
      zoneB: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

For failover, you set a comma separated list as the value, eg.

```
eureka:  
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/, http://localhost:8762/eureka/
```

Hystrix is not a load balancer, so that doesn't make sense and isn't supported.

Comment: Whenever the first instance (8761) is down, my microservice doesn't even try to connecto to the second one (8762) since it is not able to locate che config server and autowire some properties. In fact the process ends with an ERROR due to missing property. Another ms, that doesn't have any @Value looks for both eureka servers. How is it possible?